# Solve[ ] for 2 variables not returning list of two variables

Tags: equation-solving

I type into mathematica:

```
Solve[2 Sin[(Sqrt[3] x - 3 y)/2] == 2 Sin[(Sqrt[3] x + 3 y)/2], {x, y}]
```

expecting it to return a list of pairs of solutions of the form

```
{{x->x1,y->y1},{x->x2,y->y2},{x->x3,y->y3},etc...}
```

as per the documentation. But instead it gives me

[image]

which is not quite what I was expecting. How can I get this function to return a list of the pairs of solutions. I'm confused. Thanks!

Comment: You have one equation so I'd expect each of the solutions to be only for one variable (not necessarily the same in all cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each sublist in the answer is a valid solution on its own.  For example, `x -> -(π/Sqrt[3])` satisfies the equation *for any value of `y`*.

```
In[1]:= eq = 2 Sin[(Sqrt[3] x - 3 y)/2] == 2 Sin[(Sqrt[3] x + 3 y)/2];

In[2]:= sol = Solve[eq, {x, y}]

During evaluation of In[2]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

During evaluation of In[2]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

Out[2]= {{x -> -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {x -> π/Sqrt[3]}, {y -> 
   0}, {y -> -((4 π)/3)}, {y -> -((2 π)/3)}, {y -> (2 π)/
   3}, {y -> (4 π)/3}}

In[3]:= Simplify[eq /. sol]

Out[3]= {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
```

A similar but simpler case would be the equation $x y=0$.  $x=0$ is a solution for any $y$ and $y=0$ is a solution for any $x$.  The system is underdetermined, which is why Mathematica says that "equations may not give solutions for all solve variables".

Comment: Ah yes, ok thanks for explaining that.